# Outlook form VBScript for controls

Tags: forms, vbscript, outlook

I've created an Outlook form with several bound controls. I would like one of the check boxes when checked to make two text areas and their labels visible, then not be visible if the check box is unchecked. The controls that I want to make visible have the initial state of not-visible. I'm stuck on the VBScript syntax. I've been using Sue Mosher's Outlook programming book, but I'm a newby and I'm not getting it. I'd appreciate any help with this. I'm using Outlook 2010 on a Windows 7 machine. Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
Sub Item_PropertyChange(byVal Name)
Set objInsp = Item.GetInspector
Set objPage = objInsp.ModifiedFormPages("Message")
Set ckWGC = objPage.Controls("ckWGC")
Set lblState = objPage.Controls("lblState")
Set WGCState = objPage.Controls("WGCState")
Set lblCountry = objPage.Controls("lblCountry")
Set WGCCountry = objPage.Controls("WGCCountry")

If ckWGC.Value = True Then
    lblState.Visible = True
    WGCState.Visible = True
    lblCountry.Visible = True
    WGCCountry.Visible = True
Else
    lblState.Visible = False
    WGCState.Visible = False
    lblCountry.Visible = False
    WGCCountry.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to handle the CheckBox.Change event to capture when the user has checked or unchecked it.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed the subroutine statement to "Private sub ckWGC_Change()", but that didn't work.

Comment: Define "didn't work" - did the event not fire? Did you set a breakpoint on it to verify that it does fire? Did you generate the event from the list of methods for that control in the dropdown at the top of the code window?

Comment: Sorry to be vague. I changed the subroutine statement as I mentioned, then chose "Run This Form". I clicked on the checkbox, and the two items I wanted to become visible did not display.

Comment: @ Eric. I guess my edit timed out... I changed the subroutine statement as I mentioned, then chose "Run This Form". I clicked on the checkbox, and the two items I wanted to become visible did not display. The Script Editor does not have dropdowns to create events like Visual Basic does. I read in my reference book that I cannot write VBA for a bound checkbox and then share the form with others. The code had to be VBScript. If I'm confused about that part, I'll go the VBA route.

Comment: My bad - I thought you were talking about a VBA UserForm for some reason. You can only handle Click events in the legacy custom forms. Your code looks okay to me, but it's been awhile (I edited Sue's book). I'd stay away from custom forms - it's nearly impossible to debug them.

Comment: Thanks for looking it over. This is a work request, so I'll keep looking for a solution.